# Passing "event" in react-select

Tags: react-select

According to the docs in react-select (https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select), there is a property which takes a function with two parameters (value, event). I needed to get the **event**. Am I doing something wrong here?

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/62wrx9pm1k

Comment: What exactly you want from event

Comment: instead of writing handlers for every time I'm using <Select>, I'd like to use one function like:


`handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
  }`

Comment: there is no need for event there you can check first example on there official site 
You can use this.handleChange for your use case

Comment: can you provide a working example of where two Select component share the same onChange handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need state
eq

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    firstValue: "",
    secondValue: ""
  };
  handleChange = (value, state) => {
    this.setState({ [state]: value });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        name="form-field-name"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={(value) => this.handleChange(value, "firstValue")}
        options={[
          { value: "one", label: "One" },
          { value: "two", label: "Two" }
        ]}
      />
      <Select
        name="form-field-name"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={(value) => this.handleChange(value, "secondValue")}
        options={[
          { value: "one", label: "One" },
          { value: "two", label: "Two" }
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: - for this, my state name has to be "value"
- when I have two Select components, what do I do?

This doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: state = { firstChild: '', secondChild: '' }, and onChange={(value) => handleChange(value, 'secondChild')} for example, and handleChange = (values, state) => this.setState({ [state]: value })

Comment: Thank you for your help. This worked with a bit of tweaking. 

Here's a working demo if you're interested: https://codesandbox.io/s/9q24z49zvr

Answer (score 0):

In the version 2.0.11 and above to update your state for each Select with the same function, you could do it like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component{
 state={
  firstSelect: null,
  secondSelect: null
 }
 handleSelectChange = (selectedOption, { name }) => {
   this.setState({ [name]: selectedOption.value });
 }
 render() {
      return (
          <>
           <Select name="firstSelect" onChange={this.handleSelectChange} {...}/>
           <Select name="secondSelect" onChange={this.handleSelectChange} {...}/>
          </>
      )
 }
}
```